# What is the grammatical device that treats abstract concepts as having human agency?

Tags: rhetoric

What is the grammatical device that treats abstract concepts as having human agency?

For example: "As it evolved, however, science also turned itself into ideology, belief, and prejudice."

Clearly science didn't turn "itself" into anything. This seems to be a device to remove culpability from certain actors.

Does anybody know what the word is for this verbal technique?

Comment: Isn’t this the original meaning of *pathetic fallacy*? Like “angry clouds” or “the sun smiled upon them”

Comment: Search ELU SE for personification, anthropomorphism, etc, and you'll find a lot of questions discussing similar things, e.g. [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6049/anthropomorphism-vs-personification-usage).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Anthropomorphize for something like that.

Definition of anthropomorphize
transitive verb

1. to attribute human form or personality to

Comment: This is a good answer if you can provide a resource for which dictionary you got the answer from. Sources are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

John Lawler wrote in a comment:

> Terry Pratchett called it an [*anthropomorphic personification*](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Anthropomorphic_personifications), referring to Death, not Science, but it works for any Big Abstraction.